# Is there any function to find all option in config.ini

Tags: python, configparser

I have a config.ini file:

```
[setting]
ip = 192.168.1.1
port = 22
u_name = root
```

is there any function or method can i get all options (ip, port, u_name) in section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [python's config parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), we can turn the ini file into a dictionary and use that to iterate over the keys:

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

keys = [key for key in config['setting'].keys()]

print(keys)
>>> ['ip', 'port', 'u_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below replace the path with you config.ini path

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("path\\for\\config.ini")
for section in config.sections():
    print(config.options(section))
```

or simply, if you know the section name, you can get this by using the line below

```
config.options("setting")
```